# Dying leaves on "Dracaena marginata"

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-care, dracaena

I have a *Dracaena marginata* that I've had for a few years now. I moved it to a new location about a year ago - with the only noticeable difference being that it's a lower-light environment.

Similarly, for the last year or so, I've noticed that it's been dropping a fair number of leaves in a progression similar to the attached image. Usually a few dark spots appear somewhere in the middle of the leaf, and then the entire section turns limp and brown, before the leaf completely dies.

Is this related to moving the plant to a lower-light location, or is there something else happening? There continues to be new growth, but the plant looks sparser than I recall...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Good question and good illustrations; if could include overall height, current & previous watering amount & frequency, current & previous nutrient type & amount & frequency, soil, size of container, if some coarse gravel in the bottom and a hole in the bottom for good aereation & drainage, current hours of sunlight and current hours of diffused light per day, and hours of sunlight and hours of diffused light per day before moving the plant, could also be helpful. We encourage you to browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

When moving it to another place with lower light intensity, it will probably need less water. So try to reduce watering accordingly. Try to feel the upper part of the soil with your finger before watering, it should feel dry.

The plant overall looks healthy in my opinion, the yellowing and browning of the leaves are a first sign of slightly overwatering.