# New growth Dracaena Marginata leaves dropping

Tags: houseplants, leaves, dracaena

A little over month ago I posted about brown spots on my Dracaena Marginata ([Dying leaves on "Dracaena marginata"](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/54807/dying-leaves-on-dracaena-marginata)). I reduced watering slightly, and now I'm running into another issue.

On one of the stalks, 3 of the 4 growth ends are dropping considerable leaves - leaves that are dark green. One of them, so much so that only the very newest growth is left. What could be happening here? The rest of the plant continues to look healthy.

Full stalk with 1 healthy end and 3 not-so healthy:[image: Stalk with 1 healthy growth and 3 not-so-healthy]
Detail of healthy end:[image: Detail of healthy end]
Detail of the least healthy end which has dropped almost all leaves[image: Detail of the least healthy end]

Answer (score 1):

This is a result of over watering. The roots cannot get enough oxygen so the stem is dying.

Here is a quick check to diagnose this:  touch the stems where the dying leaves are.  Are they soft and can be squeezed with very little force?

If that is the case the roots are gone, the stem is dead and the leaves are just getting the news now.

Reduce the frequency of watering, improve the amount of light and cut back the stem to a few inches above the soil. It may grow back.

Comment: Thanks - this is helpful. The small stems with the dying leaves are indeed softer. As I mentioned, I had reduced watering, and when I have watered there is water in the dish, but for whatever reason, the soil is staying moist for a long period of time. I will reduce watering further and add more light. The rest of the plant still looks health so here's hoping I can salvage.

Comment: Don't water at all until the top inch  of soil feel dry to the touch, it needs time to get rid of excess moisture - if its standing in something to catch excess water, make sure you empty that after you've watered so its not left standing in water.